# An alternative to POPFile email classifier

Tags: linux, email, classification

I have been using [POPFile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POPFile) for years - but it hasn't been updated for years.

POPFile is a bayesian email classifier. Normally you'd associate this with spam - is it spam or is it not spam.  Bayesian filters are great for this. But POPFile is much more, as it can classify all your email.

So I have a series of folders set up in my IMAP account that I have told POPFile about.  POPFile watches what is in those folders, and automatically files similar emails into the same folders as they arrive into INBOX.  It tokenises the entire email to achieve this, and almost as a side effect detects and files spam.

I get more than 95% accuracy with POPFile, and it means I don't have to set up a single rule for automatic filing.

I am concerned that POPFile will stop functioning, as it loses compatibility.

Does anyone know of a similar thing?  I have looked at [SaneBox](https://www.sanebox.com/), which kind of gets there, but I'd like something that I run myself.

All the searches I do suggest alternatives that are spam filters - I don't need a spam filter - in fact, my email client does a good job at filtering spam without popfile.

In order of preference I'd says FOSS first, but if paid then so be it. As for how it functions, Linux-based would be ideal so I can have it headless, and if it was a clever sieve type approach, that would be fine, but an IMAP solution would work with any server.